# IEqualityComparer and Contains method

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable

I have this simple class with those 2 enum fields, I'm trying to find one item of this object in a collection (`List<T>`) but the Contains methods doesn't works correctly

```
public class Calculator : IEqualityComparer<Calculator>
{
    public DashboardsComputationMode ComputationMode { get; set; }
    public Modes Mode { get; set; }

    public Calculator(DashboardsComputationMode dashboardsComputationMode, Modes mode)
    {
        ComputationMode = dashboardsComputationMode;
        Mode = mode;
    }

    public bool Equals(Calculator x, Calculator y)
    {
        return (x.ComputationMode.Equals(y.ComputationMode) && x.Mode.Equals(y.Mode));
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Calculator obj)
    {
        return obj.ComputationMode.GetHashCode() ^ obj.Mode.GetHashCode();
    }
}

public enum DashboardsComputationMode
{
    Weighted = 0,
    Aggregated = 1,
    PR = 2,
    CurrentValue = 3,
    EquivalentHours = 4,
    AggregatedCorrected = 5,
    PRCorrected = 6
}

public enum Modes
{
    InstantaneousMode = 0,
    DailyMode = 1,
    MonthlyMode = 2,
    YearlyMode = 5,
    Undefined = 4,
}
```

Why could be that this test doesn't works

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
  var list = new List<Calculator>()
  {
    new Calculator(DashboardsComputationMode.PR, Modes.DailyMode),
    new Calculator(DashboardsComputationMode.CurrentValue, Modes.YearlyMode),
    new Calculator(DashboardsComputationMode.PRCorrected, Modes.MonthlyMode)
  };

  var item = new Calculator(DashboardsComputationMode.CurrentValue, Modes.YearlyMode);
  Assert.IsTrue(list[1].Equals(item));
  Assert.IsTrue(list.Contains(item));
}
```

The first assert works fine

```
Assert.IsTrue(list[1].Equals(item))
```

but the second doesn't

```
Assert.IsTrue(list.Contains(item));
```

Comment: I always assumed that list.Contains does a reference check, so you have to have the same instance, not just a match. There is an overload that will take an IEqualityComparer.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[`List<T>.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx) determines equality by using the default equality comparer (the one returned by the [`EqualityComparer<T>.Default`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763.aspx)).

Here's the MSDN explanation on how [`EqualityComparer<T>.Default`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763.aspx) works:

> The Default property checks whether type T implements the
>   [System.IEquatable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx) interface and, if so, returns an
>   [EqualityComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132123.aspx) that uses that implementation. Otherwise, it
>   returns an [EqualityComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132123.aspx) that uses the overrides of
>   [Object.Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.equals.aspx) and [Object.GetHashCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx) provided by T.

In other words, your `Calculator` class should either implement the [System.IEquatable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx) (**not** the `System.IEqualityComparer`!) interface or override the [Object.Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.equals.aspx) and [Object.GetHashCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx) methods.

Answer (score 5):

You are not using `IEqualityComparer<Calculator>` in Equals and Contains both. `EqualityComparer` has a different significance. I corrected the code for you.

```
  public class CalculatorComparer : IEqualityComparer<Calculator>
{

    public bool Equals(Calculator x, Calculator y)
    {
        return (x.ComputationMode.Equals(y.ComputationMode) && x.Mode.Equals(y.Mode));
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Calculator obj)
    {
        return obj.ComputationMode.GetHashCode() ^ obj.Mode.GetHashCode();
    }
}
public class Calculator
{
    public DashboardsComputationMode ComputationMode { get; set; }
    public Modes Mode { get; set; }

    public Calculator(DashboardsComputationMode dashboardsComputationMode, Modes mode)
    {
        ComputationMode = dashboardsComputationMode;
        Mode = mode;
    }


    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Calculator y = obj as Calculator;

        return (this.ComputationMode.Equals(y.ComputationMode) && this.Mode.Equals(y.Mode));
    }
}

public enum DashboardsComputationMode
{
    Weighted = 0,
    Aggregated = 1,
    PR = 2,
    CurrentValue = 3,
    EquivalentHours = 4,
    AggregatedCorrected = 5,
    PRCorrected = 6
}

public enum Modes
{
    InstantaneousMode = 0,
    DailyMode = 1,
    MonthlyMode = 2,
    YearlyMode = 5,
    Undefined = 4,
}
```

Now both should return true.

Comment: You need to check for null in the `calculator.Equals` method after attempting to cast the object obj, if it is `null` then return `false`.

Comment: Thanks, it works if i write Equals method as you say, in fact, implementing IEquatable i don't need to create a CalculatorComparer