# How to validate data in a List<> property in a class?

Tags: c#, list, oop, properties

I am just now studying about OOP and i have a problem with an exercise. I have a SchoolClass that has Students. The Students in a SchoolClass are not allowed to have the same number. I have the following:

```
class SchoolClass 
{
    private List<Student> students;

    public List<Student> Students
    {
        get { return this.students; }
        set
        {
            if (value == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("Students list can not be null!");
            if (value.Select(n => n.Number).Distinct().Count() != value.Count())
                throw new ArgumentException("There are students in the list with the same class number!");
            this.students = value;
        }
    }
public SchoolClass( List<Student> students)
    {
        this.Students = students;
    }
}
class Student 
{
    private uint number;

    public uint Number
    {
        get { return this.number; }
        set
        {
            if (value == 0) throw new ArgumentException("Student's number can not be null!");
            else this.number = value;
        }
    }

    public Student(string name, uint number)
    {
        this.Number = number;
    }
}
```

When I initialize two students in the Main() class with the same number, I have an ArgumentException("There are students in the list with the same class number!"); as expected. But when I have an instance of a SchoolClass (sc) and call its students list and use Add() (sc.students.Add(new Student(..)) I can insert a Student with a duplicate number. The same is with the List.InsertAt() method. I read that The getter can be done readonly using ReadOnlyCollection<...>(...) or AsReadOnly() but how will I add new students to the list in this case?

What is the best practice to avoid/solve this?

Comment: To control the collection, you'll need to build your own collection (e.g. build your own list that subclasses List<T>).

Comment: Have you considered using a `HashSet` instead of a `List`?

Comment: You could use a `HashSet<Student>` and override Equals/GetHashCode to prevent students with duplicate numbers from being added in the first place

Comment: @elmugrat, paul: I don't believe overriding Equals is appropriate in this case - changing a class' equality semantics is a very deep-reaching architectural decision. Manual validation is probably the simplest and the best choice.

Comment: @staafl:  I would say that depends on his requirements.  If a student's uniqueness is based on his number, then it would make sense.

Comment: I do not know anything about HashSets. It is coming later in the lectures.

Comment: @elmugrat, thinks like that are best avoided unless you're really really sure you need them. For example, I worked on a project where a database table was keyed by SS number, assuming it's unique - soon it turned out that some documents had typos on them and we were forced to change the database schema to be able to process them at all.

Comment: @staafl:  So you restructured your database to allow the legally impossible instead of solving the real problem of having invalid data?  Doesn't seem like the right solution to me, but hey, I wasn't there.

Comment: @elmugrat, it's the solution legal insisted on. We had signed documents - legally valid - and we needed to store them *somehow* :-)

Comment: @staafl:  Well then I guess you gotta do what you gotta do  :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using a `Dictionary`, as it is ideal for warding off duplicates according to a `Key`.  It would also be much faster than using just a `List` while checking for duplicates.

```
class SchoolClass
{
    protected Dictionary<uint, Student> _Students = new Dictionary<uint, Student>();
    public IEnumerable<Student> Students
    {
        get { return _Students.Values; }
    }

    public SchoolClass(List<Student> students)
    {
        if (students == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("Students list can not be null!");

        foreach (var student in students)
            AddStudent(student);
    }

    public void AddStudent(Student student)
    {
        if (_Students.ContainsKey(student.Number))
            throw new ArgumentException("There are students in the list with the same class number!");

        _Students.Add(student.Number, student);
    }
}
```

In the example, I expose `Students` as an `IEnumerable` so it is obvious it cannot be modified directly because it does not have `Add` or `Remove`.  `_Students`, a `Dictionary` is used as the backer/source of this property.

I also exposed an `AddStudent` method which will handle adding the students, and checking for duplicates `Numbers`.

---

**Further clarification**:

`_Students` is `protected` so that any class that is derived from `SchoolClass` can access it.  It seems very likely in this case.

I did not define a `set { }` for `Students` because it is acting as a collection that should not be directly modified.  Not creating providing a `set` makes it so the only means of modifying it is through modifying `_Students` (its backer).

Comment: I implemented your code Khan but changed protected to private Dictionary and changed the parameter of the constructor to Dictionary<uint, Student> students. But how about if a setter to the IEnumerable<Student> Students must be declared?

Comment: @ttitto Please see the `Further Clarification` I added to my answer.

Answer (score 5):

You should not be exposing a List<> property on your class - it's almost never a good idea, as it gives the user of the class way too much control over your data, and it's certainly not a good option in this case. Instead, you should expose just the properties you need, and perform your own validation:

```
// store the students as a List<>...
private List<Student> students;

// ...but expose them as IEnumerable<>.
public IEnumerable<Student> Students
{
    get { return this.students; }
}

// IEnumerable<> does not allow adding, removing, clearing, etc - 
// you know you're the only one altering the data

// and you can choose to give them restricted access with your own
// validation logic
public void AddStudent(Student student) 
{
    if (this.students.Any(s => s.Number == student.Number))
        throw new ArgumentException("Duplicate student number!");
    this.students.Add(student);
}
```

Comment: This is pretty understandable for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can mark the getter as readonly and write following method to add a new student,

```
public void AddStudent(Student s)
{
    if(!this.studentList.Contains(s))
    this.studentList.Add(s);
    else
     throw new Exception("Duplicate entry");
}
```

Contains() only helps if you have Equals Implemented in student class. Instead you can use `this.studentList.Any(s => s.Number == s.Number)`
@pauls's comment, HashSet also a good option to go...

Comment: `Contains` will do a reference comparison, and the OP wants to do a comparison on the `Student.Number`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a System.Collections.ObjectModel.KeyedCollection:

```
public class SchoolClass : KeyedCollection<uint, Student>
    {
        protected override uint GetKeyForItem(Student newStudent)
        {
            return newStudent.Number;
        }
    }
```

this will throw an ArgumentException when a student with the given number already exists

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the list from the getter as `instance.Property.Operation`, you are directly manipulating the list without going through the setter. A read-only property would probably not give you the behavior you want, since a read-only property is simply a property without a setter.

You could in fact use the `.AsReadOnly()` method, combined with new methods on your SchoolClass class, something like `AddStudent(Student student)` and `AddStudents(List<Students> students)`. The `AddStudents` method could use the `AddStudent` method in a loop, which could in turn use a private setter on your property. Validations would probably be done in the private setter.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75e8y5dd.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78dcd75.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think  you need to use List.Contains Method with custom IEqualityComparer. So you can have your comparison with other property along with number. So you will have provision without altering much code if any change required.

Please refer [**this link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14580595/iequalitycomparer-and-contains-method)