# c# searching a list of integer arrays

Tags: c#

I have a list of int arrays.

How do I search for a specific `int[]`?

Example:

```
var listIntArray = new List<int[]>();

listIntArray.Add(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 });

var array1 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
bool contains1 = listIntArray.Contains(array1);
//--> should be true

var array2 = new int[] { 4, 5, 6 };
bool contains2 = listIntArray.Contains(array2);
//--> should be false
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IEqualityComparer and Contains method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14580595/iequalitycomparer-and-contains-method)

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with LINQ.

```
bool result = listIntArray.Any(arr => arr.SequenceEqual(array1));
```